# Visual Studio 2005 Intellisense stopped working after ReSharper installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, resharper

I installed the ReSharper evaluation version and uninstalled it. Afterwards Visual Studio's Intellisense stopped working. I have restarted computer but I still have this problem.

Can anyone please help me here?

I am using Visual Studio 2005.  Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try opening Visual Studio Command Prompt and entering:

```
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon,

Resetting the dev evn with the following command fixed the problem.

devenv.exe /ResetSettings

Comment: Be sure to export any important settings you wish to keep before running this command. However, you may want to test, BEFORE restoring these settings.

Answer (score 16):

Try going to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# and checking all of the options under Statement completion.  I think Resharper disables these upon installation.

Comment: My intellisense in VS2010 Beta wasn't working. I fixed it using your tip. Thanks

Comment: I checked this as well and the only thing that worked was devenv.exe /ResetSettings

Comment: This also worked for me once my evaluation period for ReSharper 6 had completed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes deleting the ncb file helps. Go to your solution directory and find the sln file, there will also be a file with the same name and the extension ncb. Make sure Visual Studio is closed (at least don't have that project open) and then delete that file. Don't worry Visual Studio will rebuild it for you.

Comment: Does C# still produce a ncb file? I'm a C++ guy so I don't know.

Comment: My VS2005 hanged while "Updating intellisense..." when loading our VC++ solution. Deleting the ncb files fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The devenv.exe /ResetSettings was the only thing that worked for me. The full path in command prompt is as follows (for VS 2008)

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe /ResetSettings

took me a while to find so I thought I'd post this to help

Answer (score 1):

devenv /ResetSettings worked after uninstalling ReSharper. I did not have to do a repair. I did verify that the settings were checked under Text Editor > C#, but ResetSettings was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reset your Visual Studio setting by

1. End Process devenv.exe from Tast Manager if it is running .(It can close your Browser and Visual Studio)
2. Run devenv /resetuserdata from Start -> Run

Hope It can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Disable updating intelliSense like in this article:
http://amastaneh.blogspot.com/2007/11/disable-updating-intellisense.html
Eventhough for old version seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a "repair" on the installation first.  Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, select Microsoft Visual Studio 2005, click "Change/Remove".  It will load up the install dialog and give you the option to do a "repair".

YMMV, but at least it should reset a lot of the VS resources to their "fresh" state.