# "Microsoft Visual C# IntelliSense has stopped working" in project referencing F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#

After installing the F# September CTP (1.9.6.2), Visual Studio 2008 frequently gives an error "Microsoft Visual C# IntelliSense has stopped working" which promptly crashes all of Visual Studio.  I tried the tips mentioned in a [similar SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178846/visual-studio-intellisense-stopped-working) such as "devenv.exe /ResetSettings", deleting the ncb file (which actually didn't exist), and installing the latest service pack (SP1) but no luck.  Also tried reinstalling F#, nothing.  This specifically happens in a C# unit test project that references my F# project and when I start to type things like [TestMethod] or "= new Tuple<List<int>,int,int> { Item1 = ".  That's why I'm guessing it's related to F#.  Incidentally I have ReSharper installed but disabled.  Anyway, wondering if anyone else has had this problem and/or solved it.  Otherwise any thoughts/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly suggest sending the F# team a bug report: fsbugs@microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No workaround exists on Vista per Brian McNamera 9/10/08 :(

> Talked to C# team.  No workaround on Vista/Server2008.  This is supposed to be a ‘non-fatal’ Watson, but non-fatal-ness is broken on Vista, bummer, known issue.  On pre-Vista, this apparently will pop up Watson once first time this happens in VS, but not crash and then let you continue unabated.

Answer (score 1):

This is now a confirmed bug.  Here is the message from Brian McNamara on the F# team on 12/9/08:

> This is the first report of this we’ve had, but I am able to reproduce the problem on my box, so we’ll see what turns up debugging, I’ll let you know if I find a workaround. (Thanks for the detailed info.)

Comment: Is there a connect link for this, or a blog post or something that would allow tracking?  I've just been hit by this and had to turn off intellisense (boo!).