# LINQ intellisense stopped working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, linq, intellisense

What happend to my Intellisense??

When I type a line like this ...

```
Dim users = (From u In Membership.GetAllUsers Select u.UserName)
```

... I get (almost) no Intellisense when I get to the `Select u.` part. Only Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ReferenceEquals and ToString appears. Not "UserName" and the other relevant propeties of the MembershipUser class.
The code compiles and works just fine.

Any suggestions?

I tried `devenv.exe /ResetSettings` from the VS Command prompt as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178846/visual-studio-intellisense-stopped-working/178893#178893), but it didn't help.

Comment: If it helps, my c# intellisense has always been wacky on this, but I'm not sure if it's due to ReSharper interfering or not...

Comment: Nope, not in my case: Resharper is not installed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because the return type of `MemberShip.GetAllUsers` is `MembershipUserCollection`.  This collection type only implements `IEnumerable` and is not strongly type.  The compiler can only infer the type of the elements in the collection is `Object`.  Hence you get intellisense for `Object` in the select clause.

You need to tell the compiler more information about the type of the elements.  For instance if you know all of the values are `MembershipUser` instances you could use the Cast function to tell the compiler

```
From u in Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast(Of MembershipUser) ...
```

Comment: from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()... should also work, and looks rather cleaner than the .Cast syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What JaredPar told you is true , because that collection is not `IEnumerable` so you have to tell the compiler which object type inside your collection

And if that still not working be sure that you imported the linq namespace in the top of the class 
`Import System.Linq`  :)