# VS 2008 Intellisense missing: the key combination is bound to command which is not currently available

Tags: visual-studio-2008, editor, intellisense

Intellisense has stopped working for my aspx files, and I've looked at the other questions that address the issue with no solution.

When I try to format the aspx document (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D) the status bar says "The key combination is bound to command (Format Document) which is not currently available."

The outlining is no longer showing up.

[I have tried the /ResetSettings flag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178846/visual-studio-intellisense-stopped-working)  I'm not using resharper.  I've verified the settings (Tools -> Options, Text Editor) for both C#, Basic, and HTML as well as general.

How can I get this back?

Comment: This happened to me as well but I forgot I was running the application in debug mode. Attempting to format the ASPX page resulted in the same problem you are seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this by switching to design mode and then clicking on the Source.

Strangely, I had to right-click to select design view, since the design/split/source options at the bottom of the window were not present.

Once I switched to design view, the buttons came back, and when I switched back to source view everything seems to work again.

Strange.

Comment: I did not find the 'Design Mode' even in the right click. I fixed it my right clicking the file in the solution explorer and selecting 'View Markup'. Then I was able to use Ctrl+k - Ctrl+d.