# Visual studio collapsing shortcuts "not currently available"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I am baffled. The [usual shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982704/1983448) worked yesterday when I left for home. Today I started the computer, opened the project, and before writing a single line of code, wanted to collapse to definitions in an aspx file. It didn't work, and the status bar shows the message

> The key combination (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O) is bound to the command (Collapse
>   to definitions) which is not currently available

I am in normal editing mode, not in debugging. The same combination works on .cs files, but has stopped working on .aspx files. I found on the Internet posts about experiencing the same problem when updating to a new addon version, but I don't have the addons mentioned. I tried [to change into design view and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327844/vs-2008-intellisense-missing-the-key-combination-is-bound-to-command-which-is-n) but this didn't change anything.

How do I get my outlining back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command is printed when all outlining regions in the file are already collapsed to definitions. For example, if you execute the command **Collapse to Definitions** twice, you will *always* get this message the second time. The same thing happens if you execute **Expand All Definitions** when all regions in the file are already expanded. One of the following things has happened.

1. The language service did not report any outlining regions in the file. In C#, this always occurs if the following option is not checked:

   Tools → Options... → Text Editor → C# → Advanced → Enter outlining mode when files open
2. The **Edit.StopOutlining** command was executed (Edit → Outlining → Stop Outlining, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>).
3. All regions in the file are already collapsed.
4. You have identified a bug in the IDE, which you should report to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Comment: I found that "poking" outlining into life with the mouse worked for me: Open a C# file with #regions, right-click -> Outlining -> Collapse to definitions. None of the keyboard shortcuts worked, strangely. This was with "Enter outlining mode..." off, because normally I don't want it on.

Answer (score 7):

The shortcuts `Ctrl+M,O` or `Ctrl+M,Ctrl+O` do not work in .ASPX files. Try `Ctrl+M,L` instead.

Check the Edit -> Outlining menu for available actions.

Comment: Thank you for this, I don't know why it does not work but Ctrl M+L works in both ASPX and CSHTML files.

Answer (score 2):

In my case worked HotKey: "**`CTRL + M`**","**`CTRL + H`**" or "**`CTRL + M`**","**`CTRL + T`**"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally disabled outlining all to gether.

One can reactivate it by searching for "outlining" in the Visual Studio Search bar (`CTRL` + `Q`) and enabling the feature "Start Outlining automatically" again.

Hope this helps anyone encountering the same issue and finding this question!