# VC++ 2010 IntelliSense autocompletion list disappears too quickly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Any time I scroll throught the intellisense list it disappears very fast, and I have no time to seek and select which I want. I also have Visual Assist X but it doesn't help, it happens with VA enabled and also when disabled. 
Any idea which could be the cause and where to config intellisense to remain visible all time until you select something and press TAB/ENTER key? maybe there is some visible delay time config option in some file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to reset settings?

See here: [Visual Studio 2005 Intellisense stopped working after ReSharper installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178846/visual-studio-intellisense-stopped-working)

Is the problem in all solutions are you are using just one?If so, try to delete .ncb file in solution directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It happens in every solution, even making a simple new one and trying, happens also, I reset the config and disabled all extensions, but still. Thanks for help

Comment: Can you try to start MSDEV under different user account on same PC?If problem persists, there is some system wide problem (like buggy mouse/keyboard driver, etc...)

Comment: I did it as you said and in other clean account works fine, now I will seek which program or driver is making that problem in main account. Thank you very much!