# Using boost in a xll add-in created by xlw in c++

Tags: c++, boost, xlw

I am trying to use boost functions in a xll add-in that I am creating using xlw in c++. I have included the boost directory in the include directories section in the XLL property pages --> Configuration Pages --> VC++ Directories.

however, when I try to use the boost object "boost::" no member functions appear and in the bottom left hand side of the screen I get a message "IntelliSense: 'Unavailable for C++/CLI'"

Has anyone ever encountered this issue before and knows how to get around it?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the Intellisense error message is not directly related to boost and xlw.

If you are using VS2010, please have a look at the following link:
[Why is Intellisense "Unavailable for C++/CLI"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077631/why-is-intellisense-unavailable-for-c-cli)

You should still be able to use boost and compile even without Intellisense.