# Visual Studio incorrectly marking inactive code blocks when using `#ifdef`

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, conditional-compilation

My project has a bunch of `#ifdefs`. The macros used by these `#ifdef`s are usually passed through the command line using the `'/D'` option to get different build configurations. Visual studio incorrectly assumes that these macros are not defined and greys out the code blocks present inside these `#ifdef`s. The problem is not syntax highlighting - I can turn the grayed out code to colored code from Options; the main issue is that I am not able to go to the function definition of any functions present inside that `#ifdef`. I tried reading about Visual Studio [hint files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997977.aspx) but that didn't work for me.

Can anyone help me with this issue? I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Did you define several kinds of builds within VS as Configurations like Debug, Release, or are you building with makefiles? If you haven't taught VS about your /D options then I guess it can't help you. But you should be able to set up Preprocessor Definitions under project properties (Configuration Properties, C/C++, Preprocessor) to get the effect you want, right?

For each option `/DMACRO=XXX` that you pass to the compiler, specify `MACRO=XXX` in the IntelliSense Preprocessor Definitions. For each option `/DMACRO` (no value) that you pass to the compiler, specify `MACRO` in the IntelliSense preprocessor definitions.

Comment: I am building with makefiles. And I tried following instructions given here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173379%28VS.80%29.aspx). I instructed VS to enable a macro using /DMACRO=1 in the Preprocessor Definitions under Configuration Properties->NMake->Intellisense. Closed the solution, deleted .ncb file, reopened the solution, let Intellisense run and cleaned and rebuilt the solution. Things still don't seem to work.

Comment: @Ashwin You want just `MACRO=1` in that options box. The `/D` part is just for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not debugging, and you're just trying to get intellisense or whatever to react, you can always just throw up a quick `#define` to force the IDE to behave.

Seems you have a similar problem as this fellow:

[Can intellisense be enabled in VS2008 within preprocessor directive blocks like #ifndef ... #endif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515169/can-intellisense-be-enabled-in-vs2008-within-preprocessor-directive-blocks-like)

Comment: That is one solution, but there are a bunch of #ifdefs, not just one, and they are scattered around. So I would like to have get a better solution that this.