# Visual Studio Code - click on class/method name -> display definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Hey is it possible in Visual Studio Code to just click on the name of a class/method and then the program will open the file with definition of this class/method? I have big project and I am looking for a good way to move between different files.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the **class Name** and then choose **Go to Definition**. For example if you want to go to the definition of a class named **Person**, place the cursor on that word and then right click and click on **Go to Definition** or just press **F12**

Comment: It doesn't work :( I open a file, and in this file I have a class which inherits from another class. I select name of this class and click "Go to definition" and I get "No definition found for ...".

Comment: Your intellisense engine may be broken check out this link on how to resolve that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237744/go-to-definition-go-to-declaration-not-working-reliably-in-vs2010